# Prevent counting a token multiple times in Python using sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am looking to attempt to group user inputted strings into like categories.

Consider the following list of colleges:

- College of Business
- College of Business Administration
- Business School
- School of Business Administration

Currently, if I pass this through sklearn in Python, it gives me the following frequencies:

- Business, 4
- College business, 2
- School business, 2
- Business administration, 2
- College, 2
- School, 2

Here's the issue:  Once I have the departments totaled up in the "Business" category, I do not wish for it to total it up in the "College" and "School" categories.

Now consider the following departments in a hospital:

- Hematology and Oncology
- Hematology
- Oncology

Currently, if I pass this through sklearn in Python, it gives me the following frequencies:

- hematology oncology, 1
- hematology, 2
- oncology, 2

Again, once this department has been credited to the largest category, I do not wish for it to credit it again to the smaller categories.

So, my desired output is:

- hematology oncology, 1
- hematology, 1
- oncology, 1

So after sklearn counts the department in "hematology oncology" I do not want it to count it a second time under "hematology" and "oncology"

I'm having trouble achieving this.  Here is what I am currently doing:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,5), analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(user_departments['MyToken'].fillna(value='None'))
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
skwords = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

As requested (per comments), the initial list is:

```
Hematology and Oncology
Hematology
Oncology
College of Business
College of Business Administration
Business School
School of Business Administration
```

Desired result from entire dataset is something like:

```
Business, 4
hematology oncology, 1
hematology, 1
oncology, 1
```

Comment: What does your data look like? Please see the [minimal reproducible example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The list is:

Hematology and Oncology,  

Hematology,
  
Oncology,
  
College of Business,
  
College of Business Administration,
  
Business School,
  
School of Business Administration,
  
  
Desired result is something like:

Business, 4,

hematology oncology, 1,

hematology, 1,

oncology, 1,